# Мне нужна связка 2х таблиц Yii2

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

Ищу в инете, я не понимаю их примеры, решил тут напрямую спросить

В одной таблице `klient_link` нужно выбрать всех клиентов где `id_klient` => 4 и `id_active` => [3,4]
Далее в другой таблице `kliet` нужно вывести поле `name` только для тек клиентов которые указаны в таблице `klient_link` при выборке

Если я делаю выборку 2х таблиц по отдельности и потом прогоняю через foreach и сравниваю id, затем подставляю им title
То получается 2 цикла, выкидывают дубли, что совсем не красиво
Такой способ конечно не только не правильный, но и не удобный и не рабочий

Знаю что на чистом php делается это одной строчкой через JOIN
Как мне так же сделать 1 строчкой в Yii2 ?
Объясните плиз

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался!

Спасибо источнику: https://p0vidl0.info/yii2-api-guides/guide-ru-db-active-record.html

В моделе getTableLinksForm (klient_link)

```
public function getTableLinksForm()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(TableLinksForm::className(), ['id' => 'manager_id']);
    }
```

В моделе User (klient)

```
public function getUser()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(User::className(), ['manager_id' => 'id']);
    }
```

Далее в контроллере

```
$user = User::findOne([2]);
$username = $user->username;
```